# Why tkinter module raises attribute error when run via command line but not when run via IDLE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, tkinter, namespaces

**Is there a reason why the code will raise an error when run via the command line compared to when run via IDLE's `run module f5` command?**

Recently I've been trying to improve the readability and robust-ness of my code. As a result I've been trying to remove all the `from module import *` lines. I used to use `from tkinter import *` and this line of my code worked perfectly fine:

`self.path = filedialog.askdirectory()`

But now I have changed `from tkinter import *` to `import tkinter as tk` and I have changed the code accordingly:

`self.path = tk.filedialog.askdirectory()`

A file called GUI.py imports this file with: `from lib.filesearch import *` (the line of code I mentioned resides within the filesearch file.)

I run my code via IDLE and everything is fine. My GUI still works and the line `self.path = tk.filedialog.askdirectory()` works like normal however, when I run the code through windows command line I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'filedialog'
```

Here are the relevant bits from my code:

From filesearch.py

```
import tkinter as tk
    def get_path(self):
        """Store user chosen path to search"""
        self.paths = tk.filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir = FileSearch.DEFAULT)
        return self.paths
```

From GUI.py

```
from lib.filesearch import *    
    def Browse(self):
        self.BrowseB['state']='disabled'
        self.p=self.CrawlObj.get_path()
        self.AddText('Searching from Path: ' + str(self.p))
        self.BrowseB['state']='normal'
```

Unlike this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072737/why-is-this-module-not-being-found-when-i-run-the-script-but-is-in-the-interpret?rq=1) I only have one version of python installed. Namely, Python34.

Comment: Try adding a simple debug `print(tk)` to see what it actually imports. Initially differing python paths come to mind.

Comment: @Ilja from IDLE: `<module 'tkinter' from 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\tkinter\\__init__.py'>` and from command line: `<module 'tkinter' from 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\tkinter\\__init__.py'>`

Comment: That seems ok, back to the drawing board.

Comment: you need to import the submodule with `import tkinter.filedialog` to load it, the reason you don't in IDLE is because idle already did import it because it is running on tkinter

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Well that solves it. Is this also when I import tkinter I can't use the ttk submodule?

Comment: take a look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) about packages defining a `__all__` property in their `__init__.py`, it defines which submodules to load when the top level module is imported, some packages like `numpy` or `matplotlib` import **lots** of submodules which is why they take so long to load but other packages like `tkinter` and `PIL` will only load the ones you explicitly ask them to.

Comment: This is, in a sense, a bug in IDLE that its internal operation is exposed this way.  I hope to fix this someday by refactoring several modules so tkinter is not even imported into the user process before user code runs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I want to start by saying: always explicitly import submodules if you know you will use them.  The end of this answer has a more compelling case where this is important.

Because of the structure of `tkinter` you must explicitly import submodules for them to load:

```
import tkinter as tk
print(hasattr(tk,"filedialog")) # in a standard interpreter will print false
import tkinter.filedialog
print(hasattr(tk,"filedialog")) # should always print true after explicit import
```

the reason you don't need to do this in IDLE is that before your code is run, IDLE sets up some stuff in the background and ends up importing some of the tkinter libraries.  One of the [maintainers has commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163561/why-tkinter-module-raises-attribute-error-when-run-via-command-line-but-not-when/36165227#comment59972152_36163561) that this **was** effectively a bug in IDLE.

*In python 3.6.5 (and possibly earlier, only checked this version) **this specific discrepancy has been fixed** so it no longer happens for all but 2 modules I show below.*

in any version you can see a list of submodules that are loaded with some code like this:

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 03:03:55)
# standard interpreter 
>>> import sys
>>> len(sys.modules) #total number of modules automatically loaded
71
>>> sorted(name for name in sys.modules.keys() if ("." in name)) #submodules loaded
['collections.abc', 'encodings.aliases', 'encodings.latin_1', 'encodings.utf_8', 'importlib._bootstrap', 'importlib._bootstrap_external', 'importlib.abc', 'importlib.machinery', 'importlib.util', 'os.path']
>>> len(_) #number of submodules
10
```

And in IDLE:

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 03:03:55) 
# IDLE
>>> import sys
>>> len(sys.modules)
152
>>> sorted(name for name in sys.modules.keys() if ("." in name and "idlelib" not in name))
['collections.abc', 'encodings.aliases', 'encodings.ascii', 'encodings.latin_1', 'encodings.utf_8', 'importlib._bootstrap', 'importlib._bootstrap_external', 'importlib.abc', 'importlib.machinery', 'importlib.util', 'os.path', 'tkinter.constants', 'urllib.parse']
>>> len(_) #number of submodules not directly related to idlelib.
13
```

`tkinter.constants` is loaded when you just `import tkinter` so as of the version I tested, this issue still exists for only `urllib.parse` and `encodings.ascii` (and `idlelib` modules but generally production code doesn't use that)

---

This isn't necessarily an IDLE specific issue though, a worse issue is if the submodule is loaded by another library you use. Take the following code as an example:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> import http
>>> http.client
<module 'http.client' from '.../http/client.py'>
```

now lets say we wrote some other code that still used `http.client` but didn't use pandas:

```
>>> import http
>>> http.client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'http' has no attribute 'client'
```

This way you could end up with a submodule that works properly when the code that uses it loads `http.client` possibly by using a library that happens to use it but will otherwise fail.

This takes me back to my initial point - always explicitly import submodules.

Answer (score 5):

Actually it's true that the module has no attribute `filedialog`, it's a submodule and you should import it as `import tkinter.filedialog` before using it. You can use `tk.filedialog` without explicitly importing `filedialog` in IDLE because it's already imported.

```
import sys
sys.modules['tkinter.filedialog']
```

The above code will raise a `KeyError` in a standard python interpreter but it will return something like `<module 'tkinter.filedialog' from '/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/filedialog.py'>` in IDLE.