# python 3 tkinter Pycharm - error on messagebox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm, messagebox

Im writing a GUI and I say:

```
from tkinter import *
```

Further in the program theres a function wich is:

```
def nameFunc():
    messagebox.showinfo(........)
```

The problem is that by running the code in the latest Pycharm, it tells me that messagebox is not defined even if I already imported everything from tkinter, it only works if I explicitly say:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
```

This only occurs when I run the code on Pycharm, in the standard python IDLE its fine.

Why?

Comment: when you say _it only occurs when I run the code in Pycharm_ do you actually mean _it works as expected with IDLE_? Because it also happens when running python from terminal, it doesn't happen in IDLE because IDLE actually imports tkinter before the code is run.

Comment: see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163561/why-tkinter-module-raises-attribute-error-when-run-via-command-line-but-not-when/36165227#36165227) about why it is already loaded in IDLE

Comment: I double checked it and yes, it runs perfectly in the IDLE but in pycharm I need to explicitly import it.

Comment: what about from a shell? I.E. command prompt on windows or terminal on mac/linux, if you get the same issue as pycharm then this is a IDLE specific issue.

Comment: I tryied it with the windows shell and it gives me the same error as pycharm, what would you recommend doing? Just import it alone? I dont get the logic of this btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm is behaving exactly as it should, if you take a look at the [documentation on packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package):

> what happens when the user writes `from sound.effects import *`? Ideally, one would hope that this somehow goes out to the filesystem, finds which submodules are present in the package, and imports them all. *This could take a long time* and importing sub-modules might have unwanted side-effects that should only happen when the sub-module is explicitly imported.
>   
>   The only solution is for the package author to provide an explicit index of the package. The import statement uses the following convention: if a package’s `__init__.py` code defines a list named `__all__`, it is taken to be the list of module names that should be imported when `from package import *` is encountered.

tkinter does not define a `__all__` to automatically import submodules and you should be glad it doesn't import them all automatically:

```
import tkinter.__main__

print("this will only print after you close the test window")
```

the program only continues to run after a window pops up with the current tcl/Tk version and some other content is closed, to import submodules of the package you must explicitly import them with:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
```

however as I describe in my [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163561/why-tkinter-module-raises-attribute-error-when-run-via-command-line-but-not-when/36165227#36165227), because of how IDLE is built it has already loaded some of the submodules when your code is being executed in the idle Shell.

Comment: Gotcha, so basically you just told me that when I say import  " * " it imports what are by default the most "important" stuff, and messagebox is not one of them, right?

Comment: not quite, it does not import _submodules_, `tkinter.messagebox.__file__` will show you the file location of the submodule, if you go to it you will see other ubmodule such as `ttk`