# Python 3.6 - AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'filedialog'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My function was working perfectly fine few minutes ago. Did not modify the code, just installed PyAudio. I get the error as per subject. It doesn't matter if run it from command line or IDE, same error. Any ideas?

```
def DataFinder():
    #imports and initialize
    import pandas as pd
    import tkinter as tk

    finder = tk.Tk()
    finder.withdraw()

    __dataFlag = False
    #ask user to select a file
    __path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename()
    #check the extension to handle reader
    #for csv files
    if __path.endswith('.csv')==True:
        df = pd.read_csv(__path,header=0)
        return df
        __dataFlag = True
    #and for excel files
    elif __path.endswith('.xls')==True:
        df = pd.read_excel(__path,header=0)
        return df
        __dataFlag = True
    #if a file is not a supported type display message and quit
    else:
        __dataFlag = False

    #check if there is a data to be returned
    if __dataFlag==True:
        return df
    else:
        print('The file format is not supported in this version.')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why tkinter module raises attribute error when run via command line but not when run via IDLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163561/why-tkinter-module-raises-attribute-error-when-run-via-command-line-but-not-when)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the following code didn't work for me:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog
```

But the following did work:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog
```

and also this:

```
import tkinter.filedialog
import tkinter as tk
```

Hope this helps

## Note

As mentioned by [Vaidøtas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6043614/vaid%C3%B8tas-i) I., you can't import `filedialog` from `tkinter`. Because you did not import the original `tkinter` but an aliased version `tk`.

Comment: I can tell you why your first one didn't work, because you had aliased tkinter as tk and then imported filedialog from tkinter when it was aliased.

Comment: @VaidøtasI. Thank you for your comment. It helped educate myself

Answer (score 17):

Explicitly import of filedialog can solve the problem.
So, you just need to add this line to your codes:

```
import tkinter.filedialog
```

You can find more information at [Why tkinter module raises attribute error when run via command line but not when run via IDLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163561/why-tkinter-module-raises-attribute-error-when-run-via-command-line-but-not-when)

Comment: I cant `import tkinter.filedialog` but when I then the run `filedialog.askdirectory` then it throws `name "filedialog" is not defined`

Comment: What about 'tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory' ? It works?