# In python, why do you have (seemingly) to import some libraries twice?

Tags: python, import, shared-libraries

I've browsed the similarly phrased questions, but haven't found an answer:

When importing SOME libraries, it seems like I have to import the top level library in one statement, and then import the module or object I want to use in a second statement. An example that I have recently come across is:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog
```

Which results in me being able to get a file dialog in two different ways:

```
files = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
```

or

```
files = tk.filedialog.askopenfilenames()
```

Why can I not call the second option without importing `tkinter.filedialog`? I'm not familiar with the specific structure of files/packages/modules/ etc. I assume it has something to do with it.

Comment: Who says you can't use the second option?  What error did you get when you tried it?

Comment: @Prune I'm getting a "cannot find reference 'filedialog' in __init__.py"

Comment: @Prune, I see now that this was just a warning. The code compiled and ran despite the warning.

Comment: The second import line is unnecessary given the first line. You can just use `tk.filedialog.askopenfilenames()` without the need for the second line.

Comment: For me in Pycharm, without the second import, I get a stopping error: `AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'filedialog'`. With the second import, it runs just smooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED: You can check out these answers for your question:

[Python 3.6 - AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'filedialog'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45533932/python-3-6-attributeerror-module-tkinter-has-no-attribute-filedialog)

[Why tkinter module raises attribute error when run via command line but not when run via IDLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163561/why-tkinter-module-raises-attribute-error-when-run-via-command-line-but-not-when)

Comment: The question seems to be: why does `files = tk.filedialog.askopenfilenames()` give an error if you only `import tkinter as tk`

Comment: @JohanC it looks like the error was just a warning, though I am still curious as to why I would get any back talk from my IDE... so yeah I guess the question still stands.